# Equivalent of Rails "Raise" in Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I am new to Django but I have experience in Rails.

In Rails, if you want to check what one of your action/function is doing, you can use the `raise` parameter.
The execution of the action will stop, and in `http://locahost:3000` you can see the output of that function.

Example:

```rb
def answer:
    @banana = 2 + 2
    raise
end
```

If I reload localhost, a console opens and if I write `@banana` I get the result `4`.

Is there something similar in Django?

Comment: I would recommend using an IDE that supports python virtualenvs and setting breakpoints visually (like VSCode or PyCharm) which make debugging much easier than having to add the breakpoint in code.

Comment: The console isn't a result of `raise` in Rails. It's the result of you having installed the `web-console` gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `pdb`. You can check more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html#module-pdb). On your code, you can do something like this:

```py
def answer():
    banana = 2 + 2
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return banana
```

Then on your terminal if you do `banana` you'll see the result of the sum.